# How do I fix this error caused by migrating from drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold to drupal/core-composer-scaffold?

Tags: 8, migrations

I have to develop features for an old project stuck on drupal 8.5, so I figured out it would be great to update the core version to at least 8.8 for a start.
The project is setup using composer and drush, so I started following the steps listed in https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/migrating-the-composer-project-for-drupal-earlier-than-880
But I'm stucked with an error in "Migrating from drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold to drupal/core-composer-scaffold"

This is the initial composer.json

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
        "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.2",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.23",
        "drupal/ajax_comments": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.1",
        "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/colorbutton": "^1.1",
        "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
        "drupal/core": "~8.5.3",
        "drupal/devel": "^1.2",
        "drupal/eu_cookie_compliance": "^1.0",
        "drupal/filefield_paths": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.0",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.5",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.3",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.2",
        "drupal/quick_node_clone": "^1.10",
        "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^2.12",
        "drupal/smtp": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.4",
        "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^1.5",
        "drupal/viewsreference": "^1.2",
        "drupal/webform": "^5.0@RC",
        "drupal/yoast_seo": "2.0-alpha3",
        "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
        "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "~8.5.3"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ],
        "files": ["load.environment.php"]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "drupal-scaffold": "DrupalComposer\\DrupalScaffold\\Plugin::scaffold",
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
            "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
        }
    }
}
```

Running the first step (Migrating from webflo/drupal-core-require-dev to drupal/core-dev) was pretty strait forward but from the second I'm stuck with an error as I run `composer require drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^8.8`

This is the full error message

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.11
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.10
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.9
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.8
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.7
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.6
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.5
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.4
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.3
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.2
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.0
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.12
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.11
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.10
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.9
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.8
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.7
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.6
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.4
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.3
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.2
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.0-rc1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.0-rc1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.0-beta3
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.0-beta2
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.0-beta1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.0-beta1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.0-alpha1
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.9.x-dev
    - drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.x-dev conflicts with drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold[2.5.4].
    - drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.x-dev conflicts with drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold[2.5.4].
    - drupal/core-composer-scaffold 8.8.x-dev conflicts with drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold[2.5.4].
    - Installation request for drupal/core-composer-scaffold ^8.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-composer-scaffold[8.8.0, 8.8.0-alpha1, 8.8.0-beta1, 8.8.0-rc1, 8.8.1, 8.8.10, 8.8.11, 8.8.12, 8.8.2, 8.8.3, 8.8.4, 8.8.5, 8.8.6, 8.8.7, 8.8.8, 8.8.9, 8.8.x-dev, 8.9.0, 8.9.0-beta1, 8.9.0-beta2, 8.9.0-beta3, 8.9.0-rc1, 8.9.1, 8.9.10, 8.9.11, 8.9.2, 8.9.3, 8.9.4, 8.9.5, 8.9.6, 8.9.7, 8.9.8, 8.9.9, 8.9.x-dev].
    - Installation request for drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold (locked at 2.5.4) -> satisfiable by drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold[2.5.4].
```

I'm considering giving up on the upgrade since this is only the beginning and it should be the easy part since I don't have to handle the database yet.

How do I fix these errors?

Comment: Looks like you didn't follow the instructions in the link - specifically it says you need to remove `drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold` first

Comment: Well, I did run composer remove drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold --no-update and still got this message, hence my post. My current composer.json no longer has "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.2" but there is still a line mentionning drupal-scaffold in the scripts, maybe the problem come from this line ?

Comment: I would look at the content of composer.lock, as _drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold (locked at 2.5.4)_ seems to suggest that file still has a reference to drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold.

Comment: Hi, please create a **new** post if you have a new question. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The *Installation request for drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold (locked at 2.5.4) -> satisfiable by drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold[2.5.4]* part means the composer.lock file contains a reference to that version of the *drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold* package.

Since you already ran `composer remove drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold`, remove the line referring to the *drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold* package from the composer.lock file, and run again `composer require drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^8.8`.

Answer (score 3):

In the end running `composer remove drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold` instead of `composer remove drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold --no-update` solved the issue. No idea why the line specified in the doc has this --no-update.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in answers - you can always create a new post if you have a new question. Thanks